# Filtering metadata by INSPIRE theme

Tags: geonetwork

We have GeoNetwork installed in version 3.4.3. For some reason on the start page, there is no possibility to change the filtering of metadata based on INSPIRE themes.
[image: Screensshot demonstrating problem]

We have INSPIRE Directive option enabled and INSPIRE thesaurus is added to the catalogue. What are we missing? How can we enable this functionality?

Comment: Try to reindex in _Admin Console -> Tools_. Maybe the INSPIRE theme is not indexed yet.

Comment: The metadata catalogue was indexed many times.